# Unexpected result in java

Tags: java

```
public class CompileTest{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Class.forName("string");
        System.out.println("Inside main");
        OutputStream o=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }
}
```

This is my code when I compile this then

```
C:\Users\MOHD RASHID\Documents\java>javac CompileTest.java

 CompileTest.java:8: error: incompatible types: ByteArrayOutputStream cannot be converted to OutputStream
 OutputStream o=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

is generated but should not be generated and forName() method throw ClassNotFoundException which is compile time exception and hence must be caught or handle but this error is also not generated? please tell me what should I do?

Comment: For your second part of the question (concerning the OutputStream), are you importing the proper classes? You code compiles and runs just fine if I wrap the `Class.forName` call in try/catch.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Did you perhaps create your own `OutputStream` or `ByteArrayOutputStream` class? Also this code will not compile from other reason: you are not handling exceptions possibly thrown from `Class.forName`.

Comment: what packages are you importing? By the error message, looks like you have somewhere defined OutputStream or ByteArrayOutputStream, and didn't import the java default ones

Answer (score 3):

Your compile error is likely due to the fact that the `OutputStream` type shown in your code is something other than `java.io.OutputStream`. Check your import statements and if you see an `OutputStream` in a different package, change it to `java.io.OutputStream`. Then your code should compile. And it will also throw the `ClassNotFoundException` at runtime since `string` is not a valid class (should be `java.lang.String`).

Answer (score 2):

```
Class.forName("string")
```

This would throw a ClassNotFoundException if no class with the name string could be found. Perhaps you meant String.

Anyway ClassNotFoundException is a checked exception and any method that throws a checked exception should be wrapped in a try-catch block and the corresponding exception should be handled. Another option is to declare that main() throws this checked exception instead.

There should not be any error for the following line as long as your imports don't conflict or if the wrong OutputStream or ByteArrayOutputStream is imported:

```
OutputStream o=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is the clue.

```
error: incompatible types: ByteArrayOutputStream cannot be converted to OutputStream
```

If you had used the builtin classes the message would read

```
error: incompatible types: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream cannot be converted to java.io.OutputStream
```

Note: there is no package name indicating you have your own implementations and your ByteArrayOutputStream doesn't extend or implement your OutputStream

Answer (score 0):

Thank you...my problem have been solved.Actually there was another class ByteArrayOutputStream in same folder('java' in my directory structure). And instead of accessing java.io.OutputStream,the class ByteArrayOutputStream in the same folder is accessible.and this class is not extending OutputStream That is why error "ByteArrayOutputStream can not be converted to OutputStream" is shown.and because of this mistake,statement Class.forName(); does not show the exception "ClassNotFoundException must be caught or declared to be thrown"